# rake aborted ActiveRecord:Statement invalid in mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When i run `rake db:migrate` i get following error..

```
E:\railsapp\article>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'referential_constraints' in information_schema: 
SELECT fk.referenced_table_name AS 'to_table',
       fk.referenced_column_name AS 'primary_key',
       fk.column_name AS 'column',
       fk.constraint_name AS 'name',
       rc.update_rule AS 'on_update',
       rc.delete_rule AS 'on_delete'
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage fk
JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
USING (constraint_schema, constraint_name)
WHERE fk.referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
  AND fk.table_schema = DATABASE()
  AND fk.table_name = 'blogs'
  AND rc.table_name = 'blogs'
Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'referential_constraints' in information_schema
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: what is `referential_constraints` ?

Comment: Well, `referential_constraints` is missing (i'm not sure why) so it's not a rails error, so i tagged your question with `mysql`.

Comment: What version of `mysql` are you running?

Comment: Are you sure you've created your tables ? Try running `rake db:reset`.